# JXL Support for excel 2007 format

Tags: jxl

I my app, I have used JXL to parse XLS sheets.

Now as per the client requirement I need to provide support for XLSX (Excel 2007) format also.

But it seems that JXL has not published any version which supports  XLSX(Excel 2007) format.

Can anyone suggest me any way of JXL which is compatible with XLSX format ?

OR Is it required to change the API OR I can process XLSX file with JXL ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I visited JXL api and it seems that they are not providing support for xlsx format.

So I changed my api to Apche POI 3.9.

It has good functionality for xlsx/xls processing.

Comment: Could u give an example of the same? I am not able to make apache POI work with xlsx and docx. See my questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872019/creating-a-docx-file-using-poi-ooxml-jar-file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872636/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-while-creating-a-xlsx-file-using-apache-poi

Answer (score -3):

add  following two jars then it will work :

xmlbeans and dom4j

Comment: It seems that you are misleading by this answer. Please visit JXL website http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/. Here they have mentioend support only for microsoft office 2003.