# How to create .docx files and .xlsx files on Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, excel, apache-poi

I have a very simple question: How to create **.docx** and **.xlsx** files on Android. Before someone marks this as duplicate, let me tell you that I have extensively tried creating them using Apache POI and my attempts are described in these questions:

[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while creating a .xlsx file using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872636/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-while-creating-a-xlsx-file-using-apache-poi)

[Creating a .docx file using poi-ooxml jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872019/creating-a-docx-file-using-poi-ooxml-jar-file)

However, as described in those links, I am getting the **java.lang.verify error**. These are the jar files I have finally imported into my reference libraries:

- dom4j-1.6.1.jar
- poi-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
- poi-ooxml-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
- stax-api-1.0.1.jar
- xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
- poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
- commons-codec-1.5.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.jar
- junit-4.11.jar
- log4j-1.2.13.jar

but now it doesn't compile at all, and says this on the console

```
Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.

This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
going on.

However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
It is also often of questionable legality.

If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.

If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
building an application, then be forewarned that your application
will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
system. You will be to blame for this problem.

If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.

[2014-02-19 16:59:24 - test] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2014-02-19 16:59:24 - test] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

Please advise as to what I am to do.

**EDIT:**

My *end purpose* is: I wish to **create** .docx and .xlsx files and **add some content** to them. Once the files are created, I should be able to successfully **view** them on the **PC system** which I have connected the phone to.

**EDIT 2:** Found a workaround to generate **.xlsx** files by **removing** all these dependencies and using  **jspreadsheet-1.0** jar file. But I still don't know what to do for **.docx** files.

**UPDATED QUESTION:**

It seems my problem lies with using the POI jar files which is not supported by Android. Can someone please supply me the link where I can get POI **specifically** for **Android**?

Or, can someone please tell me how to create **.docx** files to which I can add content, and such that they can be viewed?

Comment: What exactly where you trying to do when you got that error message?  It looks like you were trying to add missing java or javax classes, something the Android toolchain unhelpfully tries to stop you from doing.  If that's what you were doing, then just rename the needed classes where they are used, and then implement them under the new names.  But if at this point all you want is a pointer to a library, that type of request has been deemed to be off topic for Stackoverflow.

Comment: I am trying to generate a valid readable .docx file. Most suggest apache poi so I went ahead with it. But I am unable to generate such a **readable** file. Essentially I just want a way to do so, and the major part of my post describes my *attempt* at doing so.

Comment: The problem is that you do not meaningfully describe your attempt or the current problem with it., in a way that would allow anyone to assist you in solving it. Instead you've switched your question to asking for a reference to a library.  Questions of that type are closed as off-topic as a matter of policy.

Comment: I have described my question as meaningfully as I can in my edits and updated question subsections, so that there should be no elements of doubt. I have also updated *my own* progress in my attempts to solve the question. If you still have any doubt as to what my  problem is, please let me know what *exactly* you find confusing or unclear.

Comment: I will definitely refine my questions accordingly. Also, I am not asking for any library reference, since I have described the libraries I myself have found on the net and tried. That first part of my **updated question** merely enquires whether I am to use it separately in different way or should I use a different version **for Android** or not. Also, that was one of the conclusions I came to after many attempts, which is why I posted it so that the experts here could show what I was still doing wrong.

Comment: You have failed to provide sufficient information about the code being built to allow anyone to determine the cause of the java/javax namespace error.  That appears to be the last on-topic thrust of your question.

Comment: That is why I posted that entire log, because I *don't know* what caused it (I have also indicated that *perhaps* I wasn't using Android related POI jars and that I needed clarification on that - which I have clearly indicated in my updated question). I had been using apache POI successfully to create .xls files before, so I tried the same with .xlsx, using **XWPF** related classes of POI, but it didn't work. I hope you checked the two **links to the related questions** I have posted regarding my problem. So please let me know what information exactly you need regarding the code being built.

Comment: @Gautham I have one issue related to `xlsx` file, please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22037169/file-not-exist-occurs-only-for-xlsx-file-in-android?noredirect=1#comment33413614_22037169. If you have any idea, share with me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [docx4j](http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j) to create **.docx** files.

**docx4j is an open source (Apache v2) library for creating, editing, and saving OpenXML "packages", including docx, pptx, and xslx.**

So you need to use [JAXB-based Java library for Word docx](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/tree/android).

This is a helpful tutorial for that:
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/java-word-docx-documents-with-docx4j.html

Then  your next question "is that compatible with the android ? " Look at this: [JAXB can be made to run on Android](http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2012/05/jaxb-can-be-made-to-run-on-android/)

I think this will help you.

Comment: Not compatible with gradle

Answer (score 2):

Use  [Apache POI library](http://poi.apache.org/) only because It is the best out there.

Google also uses it in its [Quick Office](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.quickoffice.android) Application for Android.

For the .***x files like docx and xlsx, It might have some limits on the allowed functions in Dalvik.

Answer (score 1):

normally you only must to do this:

```
FileOutputStream archivoSalida;
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sht = wb.createSheet("Conciliacion");
...
...
archivoSalida = new FileOutputStream(fileDestination);
wb.write(archivoSalida);
archivoSalida.close();
```

But it seems that your problem is not in the code. Is in the libraries and the compilation.
I'am wrong?

Comment: It seems to be in the libraries and/or compilation. As described in my question I overcame two exceptions to finally reach here. Only now, it doesn't even compile :)

Comment: You must to add the library dependences:

Comment: please elaborate. In case you mean I have to import those jars to my eclipse project, then yes, I have done that.

Comment: If you download the "poi-bin-x.xx-FINAL-...tar" you will find two folders: lib, and ooxml-lib. Add this jars to your project

Comment: No. You don't have all the dependecy libraries: You still need log4j, junit, commons-codec, commons-logging,

Comment: So you are saying that I should add a total of 10 jar files right?

Comment: You need 7 jars, and all are in the folders "lib" and "ooxml-lib", in the compressed tar file.

Comment: Yes, the six jar files I have mentioned in my question (of which three are from "ooxml-lib") and four more from the "lib" folder. I have included them all and I still face the issue.

Comment: Add a more detailed log here, please

Comment: Updated my question. Please check.

Comment: Mmmmm. Please, send your package structure. It's possible you're using java.xxx.yyy package structure? Your packages can't be started by the reserved word "java"

Comment: You mean the packages under my android src? No they start with com.xxx.yyy

Answer (score 1):

Try using  http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/

The jar file has a very simple apis, to manipulate/create Excel sheets.

Comment: Is it Android compatible though? Also, isn't it restricted to just the `.xls` file format, therefore not suitable for either `.xlsx` or `.docx` which the question is all about?

Comment: yes jexcel is restricted to .xls, offers no support for .xlsx