# File not exist occurs only for XLSX file in android

Tags: android

I have trying to open `XLSX` file in android using intent filter to select existing XLSX reader application but always getting file not found exception. The same code works fine for `XLS` file. I added `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in manifest and file path being correct only. File also available in SD Card. My tablet have `sheet to go` and `OfficeSuite` application to read `XLSX` files. Even i can able to open my `XLSX` file by clicking on it. But trying to open via my application gives problem. For `XLSX` file my code always goes to `else` part. Thanks in advance.

```
private void openSpreadSheet(String fileCompletePath) {

        File file = new File(fileCompletePath);


        if (file.exists()) {
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "File exist");
                Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "No application found to display spread sheet.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "File not exist");
        }
    }
```

If i remove if condition, then intent filter asked for choose application after choosing application, that selected application shows this error `File not found(/Duplicate.xlsx:open failed:ENOENT(No such file or directory)).`

**Found Solution**
    Issue comes because I gave wrong file path.

Comment: try to set setDataAndType and try  `intent.setDataAndType(uri,"application/*");` it's works

Comment: @MD OP says `file.exists()` is returning `false`...

Comment: @MD but i can not enter into if block. file.exists() return false for xlsx files.

Comment: @SathishKumar check this way `if(file.exists() && file.length()!=0)` and also add   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` into manifest.xml

Comment: @MD i got bat file format while doing that exists() condition so here problem is file  extension

Comment: @SathishKumar you got it. cross check your file format

Comment: @SathishKumar you must cross check your Path.

Comment: @MD yeah i checked, by duplicating that file with `XLS` extension. I can able to open this duplicated `XLS` file. Both file are in same folder only.

Comment: @SathishKumar added read permission into manifest?

Comment: @MD yeah i had add that too but no use

Comment: @SathishKumar try this create a fresh XLSX file using Office Excel and add into folder

Comment: @MD I tried but not works

Comment: Try printing the file path and check if it is correct.

Comment: @Priya yeah i checked that too, path being correct only. And here, the extension `XLSX` is problem. Same file within same folder but extension 'XLS' works fine but not 'XLSX' works. `File file=new File('../../dup.xlsx');` this line gives bad file format warning too. Don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Can you post your log?

Comment: `02-26 15:25:29.002: D/Input(25982): Couldn't open '/dev/touch' (No such file or directory)

02-26 15:25:29.003: D/Input(25982): tpd read x fail: Bad file number

02-26 15:25:29.003: D/Input(25982): tpd read y fail: Bad file number

02-26 15:25:29.067: D/OrderActivityCR(25982): File not exist` this is my log.

Comment: Use isFile() method to check whether .xlsx extension can be considered as a file or not.

Comment: @Priya `02-26 16:56:10.288: V/isFile()(18785): false` that returns false.

Comment: Are you creating that .xlsx file  programatically or is it already created and stored in that path??

Comment: @Priya Issue is with my file path, sorry to waste your time and i was wrongly referred file path in logcat. Finally, Thank you so much for your response.

Comment: If you are not going to read the file, just give the uri as
Uri path =Uri.parse(fileCompletePath)

Comment: No problem.. I'm glad as you found the mistake..