# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while creating a .xlsx file using Apache POI

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to create a .xlsx file using Apache POI. This is my code:

```
FileOutputStream outputStream1=null;
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("data");

try {
    target.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    outputStream1 = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/file_A/"+"test_Ab"+".xlsx");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

for(int i=0;i<iteration;i++)
{
    XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(i);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue("dsfasdf");
}

try {

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(target);
    workbook.write(out);
    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get the following exception when run the code:

```
02-19 11:48:13.387: E/AndroidRuntime(18736): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 11:48:13.387: E/AndroidRuntime(18736): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook
02-19 11:48:13.387: E/AndroidRuntime(18736):    at com.example.filegenerator.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:248)
02-19 11:48:13.387: E/AndroidRuntime(18736):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4101)
02-19 11:48:13.387: E/AndroidRuntime(18736):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17088)
02-19 11:48:13.387: E/AndroidRuntime(18736):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-19 11:48:13.387: E/AndroidRuntime(18736):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-19 11:48:13.387: E/AndroidRuntime(18736):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153) 
02-19 11:48:13.387: E/AndroidRuntime(18736):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5096)
02-19 11:48:13.387: E/AndroidRuntime(18736):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 11:48:13.387: E/AndroidRuntime(18736):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-19 11:48:13.387: E/AndroidRuntime(18736):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
02-19 11:48:13.387: E/AndroidRuntime(18736):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
02-19 11:48:13.387: E/AndroidRuntime(18736):    at   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am using the **poi-3.7.jar**. What is the problem here?

Comment: Exception says that `XSSFWorkBook` not found, you need to import jar which contains the this class. Probably you have not added the jar file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916350/what-give-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror

Comment: Could you please specify the link for that jar?

Comment: http://poi.apache.org/download.html

Comment: @nidhin: I am trying to do this in an android app, will update my question.

Comment: @GauravGupta: Should I add all the jars in that?

Answer (score 2):

As detailed on the [Apache POI components page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components), to use the OOXML code like XSSF, you need both the `poi` and `poi-ooxml` jars on your classpath, along with their dependencies.

The latest version of Apache POI, as of writing, is 3.10. I'd suggest you go download the binary release package, in there you'll find all the POI jars, along with all their dependencies. The [components page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) will help you work out which you need, but for working with XSSF the short answer is you'll basically need all of them!

Answer (score 0):

you need to download [poi-ooxml-3.9.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/p/Downloadpoiooxml39jar.htm)

Comment: when i run this, I get a java.lang.VerifyError. I have posted a similar query here . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872019/creating-a-docx-file-using-poi-ooxml-jar-file Please help out.

Comment: I took care of that, but now this is what happens : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877532/how-to-create-docx-files-and-xlsx-files

Comment: See my edited question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877532/how-to-create-docx-files-and-xlsx-files

Answer (score 0):

Cause of `NoClassDefFoundError` is: Definition of class specified in exception was need to execute the code, but it could not be found under the specified package.

Root cause: Usually it turns out that either jar file containing that Class definition was added or it was not added to build path.

You can download apache POI jars for various releases [here](http://poi.apache.org/download.html)

Comment: I have done that.. but should I include **all** the jars in that folder in my reference libraries?

Comment: YOu can include all the jars supplied in the package.

Comment: http://poi.apache.org/overview.html see this page for figuring out dependencies of jar file for better clarity

Comment: When i added the poi-3.10 and poi-3.10-ooxml jars and ran it, I got the following errors : java.lang.Verify error

Comment: Now, this is some separate issue. Log it as another SO question after some research.

Comment: I have already logged this question in SO after a lot of research. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872019/creating-a-docx-file-using-poi-ooxml-jar-file

Answer (score 0):

I also think you do not import the poi-3.7.jar into your project!  first, you should create a folder lib, then copy the jar package file to this lib,then switch to build path,  you can google it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it works only if your app contains these libraries:

```
compile files('libs/dom4j-1.6.1.jar')
compile files('libs/stax-api-1.0.1.jar')
compile files('libs/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar')
compile files('libs/poi-3.10.1-20140818.jar')
compile files('libs/poi-ooxml-3.10.1-20140818.jar')
compile files('libs/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10.1-20140818.jar')
```

You can download them here: [here](https://archive.apache.org/dist/poi/release/bin/), all in the 'poi-bin-3.10.1-20140818.zip' archive.

And please do not try to install a newer version, it will not work (at least for Android), only 3.10.1 and lower.